# Nginx Ingress timeouts / connection drops

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Consider this NodePort service:

```
k describe service myservice
...
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.15.248.153
Port:                     myservice  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 myservice  30593/TCP
Endpoints:                10.12.223.56:8080
```

Consider a request taking exactly 120s:

```
# time curl -vkH 'http://myservce:8080/test?timeout=120'
*   Trying 10.15.248.153...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected myservice (10.15.248.153) port 8080 (#0)
...
< HTTP/1.1 200

real    2m0.023s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.009s
```

This is good. So I configure nginx-ingress timeouts:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "900"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "900"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "60"
```

I can confirm it is in the nginx.conf:

```
proxy_connect_timeout                   60s;
proxy_send_timeout                      900s;
proxy_read_timeout                      900s;
```

So now, I try enter the nginx ingress pod and try to access myservice via nginx-ingress:

```
time curl -vkH 'http://127.0.0.1/myservice/test?timeout=120'
```

But this time I get empty response - sometimes after 35s, sometimes after 90s, but it will get there:

```
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I have no mored ideas what might be happening. It looks as if the nginx was randomly restarted and my connections were dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the nginx process was constantly reloaded - every 30 seconds. With each reload, all connections were dropped.

The solution is to set:

```
worker-shutdown-timeout: "900s"
```

In the nginx-ingress `config-map`.

Comment: sorry, could you please specify where the nginx-ingress config-map is located?

Comment: `k get config-map` and then `k edit config-map` (or shorter `k edit cm`)