# Kubernets ingress-nginx timeout in 120s

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I have one api, which will run about 4 minutes. I have deployed it on kubernetes with ingress-nginx. All api work normally except the long-run api, it always return 504 Gateaway as below:
[image]

I have check in stackoverflow, and try some solution, none of it work for me.

any help is welcome.

[Kubernetes Ingress (Specific APP) 504 Gateway Time-Out with 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945381/kubernetes-ingress-specific-app-504-gateway-time-out-with-60-seconds)

I have changed ingress config as below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{  .Values.releaseName }}-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: "keepalive_timeout 3600s; grpc_read_timeout 3600s; grpc_send_timeout 3600s;client_body_timeout 3600s;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3601"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3601"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3601"
    # nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    # nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    # nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream: "error non_idempotent  http_502 http_503 http_504"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/retry-non-idempotent: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "5"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "1"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |-
    #   location  /HouseKeeping/Health/Healthz {
    #       deny all;
    #       return 403;
    #     }
    #   location  /InternalApi/ {
    #     deny all;
    #     return 403;
    #   }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
      http {
        client_max_body_size 100m;
      }
      location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy-connect-timeout: 3602;
        proxy-read-timeout: 3602;
        proxy-send-timeout: 3602;
      }
      
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{  .Values.apiDomain }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{  .Values.releaseName }}-web-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I also change the configMap for ingress-nginx-controller to add below config:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
  proxy-read-timeout: "300"
  proxy-send-timeout: "300"
kind: ConfigMap
```

I also used command to get ingress-nginx's conf, it seems okay

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx exec ingress-nginx-controller-6cc65c646d-ljmrm cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | tee nginx.test-ingress-export.conf
```

```
 # Custom headers to proxied server

 proxy_connect_timeout                   3601s;
 proxy_send_timeout                      3601s;
 proxy_read_timeout                      3601s;
```

it still timeout in 120 seconds.

Comment: Check typos : nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "5"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "1" (Underscore placed in place of Hyphen).

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy No, the issue still there.

Comment: Please revise your question..

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Okay, the typo cause another issue, after I fix the typo, that issue has gone,  but the 120 seconds timeout issue still there.

Comment: Can you check this [Custom Configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/)

Comment: yes, I have added proxy-connect-timeout like "Custom Configuration" , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592545/increase-proxy-send-timeout-and-proxy-read-timeout-ingress-nginx).

Answer (score 1):

**Typo**

Replace below (ingress config):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "5"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "1"
```

In place of (ingress config)

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy_next_upstream_timeout: "5"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy_next_upstream_tries: "1"
```

**Edit :**

Check this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2007#issuecomment-656662251) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: No, it cannot work. I have followed "comment" but it still timeout 120 seconds. I have updated my original question to add the client-body-timeout

Comment: Please see [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008835/nginx-ingress-timeouts-connection-drops) and also [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838808/nginx-reports-upstream-connection-timeout) which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you please post your exact error message or else screen sheet of the error?